# Send additional data to Telerik MVC grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using AJAX bound Telerik MVC grid. I am sending data for the grid using a code like the following:

```
return View(new GridModel(...));
```

I want to be able to send additional data to client in the same action method. For example I need to send a single int value Total, which is to be shown above the grid (this value must be fetched from db, it cannot be evaluated client-side).

Please share any ideas.

Comment: I found the answer in the following Telerik forum thread http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/receiving-metadata.aspx

Comment: Can you post the solution to your problem please, the link you posted doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your desired result, you could add a client footer template bound to the property passed down from your model as follows:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.UnitPrice)
       .ClientFooterTemplate("<#= Total #>");
```

There is also a good example detailing the [use of server aggregates](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/aggregatesserverside) on the Telerik site if you wanted to work these out using aggregate functions in the future.

Comment: Thanks for you response, but it's not exactly what I needed, I have resolved the issue, see the answer.